Evaluating step functions
Please guys, how do I tell Mathematica to return f(a-b)= 1 if a=b and 0 otherwise?
This means that f(0)=1 and f(x)=0 for x>0.

Hi Mark, welcome to Mma.SE. Please start by taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. What have you tried? How did you search and what did you find? Where is your code? Why do other questions on this site not address your issue?

Have a look at DiscreteDelta, https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteDelta.html . However, there are cases when this is not a good solution. For instance, it might not work well with numerical solvers. You have to tell us about the purpose.

You can do f[0]:=1; f[x_]:=0/;x>0 or use Piecewise g[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, x == 0}, {0, x > 0}, {Nothing, True}}] screen shot https://i.sstatic.net/kZeHJy2b.png

f[a_, b_] := KroneckerDelta[a, b]

f = 1 - Unitize@# &?

Integer or Real input? Ditto for output? If Real input, compare with tolerance? (Sort of impossible to check a == b if passed a - b, tho, so maybe "a=b" does not mean a == b in the Real case.)
